# How to stop CMD (from subprocess.popen) closing when an Exception is raised?

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, subprocess, popen

I'm spawning multiple CMDs with a given python file, using `subprocess.popen`. All with an `input()` at the end. The problem is if there is any raised exception in the code the window just closes and I can't see what happened to it.

I want it to either way stay open no matter the error. so I can see it. Or get the error back at the main window like this script failed to run because of this..

I'm running this on Windows:

```
import sys
import platform
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

pipelines = [("Name1","path1"),
         ("Name2","path2")]

# define a command that starts new terminal
if platform.system() == "Windows":
  new_window_command = "cmd.exe /c start".split()
else:  #XXX this can be made more portable
  new_window_command = "x-terminal-emulator -e".split()
processes = []
for i in range(len(pipelines)):
  # open new consoles, display messages
  echo = [sys.executable, "-c",
        "import sys; print(sys.argv[1]);  from {} import {}; obj = {}(); obj.run();  input('Press Enter..')".format(pipelines[i][1],pipelines[i][0],pipelines[i][0])]
  processes.append(Popen(new_window_command + echo + [pipelines[i][0]])) 

for proc in processes:    
  proc.wait()
```

Comment: The way to get a new console is with the option `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, and run the command directly instead of via `cmd.exe /c`. CMD's `start` command will not wait and set the exit code, not by default. It can be made to work by combining the `/w` option and CMD's `exit` command, but it's not worth it unless the command only works via `start`.

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. I can change it to use the new console flag, but then how should I stop it to close, or get the raised exception on the main window? I see that If i print out the wait function I get 0 or 1 but I did get 1 for the raised exception from the code and 0 for the keyboard interuption.

Answer (score 0):

To see the error, try to wrap the desired code fragment in `try` / `except`

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thats not a bad Idea but I don't think I'm able to do that in the string what am I passing